# Creat boost grd graph in order to run dijkstra shortest_path and A* algorithm fro dijkstra

Tags: c++, boost, graph, grid

I am new in Boost and I'm trying to write a program to Dijkstra-SP and Dijkstra with A*. The graph take random edge weight between [0,100]. I have many problems as we can see and I need some suggestions in order to solve it.

```
#include <boost/graph/grid_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::grid_graph<2> grid;
typedef boost::graph_traits<grid>::vertices_size_type vertices_size_type;
typedef boost::property_map<grid, boost::vertex_index_t>::const_type GridIndexMapType;

GridIndexMapType gridIndexMap(get(boost::vertex_index, graph));

shared_array_property_map < vertex_descriptor, property_map<graph_t, vertex_index_t>::const_type>
    p_map(num_vertices(graph), get(vertex_index, graph));
shared_array_property_map<double, property_map<graph_t, vertex_index_t>::const_type>
    d_map(num_vertices(graph), get(vertex_index, graph));


struct edge_weight_map;
namespace boost 
{
    template<>
    struct property_map< graph_t, edge_weight_t > {
        typedef edge_weight_map type;
        typedef edge_weight_map const_type;
    };
}

/*
 Map from edges to weight values
*/
struct edge_weight_map 
{
    typedef double value_type;
    typedef value_type reference;
    typedef edge_descriptor key_type;
    typedef boost::readable_property_map_tag category;

    const graph_t& m_graph;

    edge_weight_map(const graph_t& g)
    :m_graph(g) { }
    reference operator[](key_type e) const; // implemented below
};

typedef boost::property_map<graph_t, boost::edge_weight_t>::const_type
    const_edge_weight_map;
typedef boost::property_traits<const_edge_weight_map>::reference
    edge_weight_map_value_type;
typedef boost::property_traits<const_edge_weight_map>::key_type
    edge_weight_map_key;

namespace boost{
    // PropertyMap valid expressions
    edge_weight_map_value_type get(const_edge_weight_map pmap, 
    edge_weight_map_key e) {
        return pmap[e]; }
    // ReadablePropertyGraph valid expressions
    const_edge_weight_map get(boost::edge_weight_t, const graph_t&g) {
        return const_edge_weight_map(g); }
    edge_weight_map_value_type get(boost::edge_weight_t tag, const graph_t& g, 
    edge_weight_map_key e) 
    { return get(tag, g)[e]; }
}


edge_weight_map::reference
edge_weight_map::operator[](key_type e) const {
    vertex_descriptor t = target(e,m_graph);
    vertex_descriptor s = source(e,m_graph);
     // f = f(t,s)
    return f;
}

class grid_graph {
    public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const grid_graph&);
    //friend grid_graph random_maze(std::size_t, std::size_t);

     grid_graph():m_grid(create_grid(0, 0)) {};
     grid_graph(std::size_t x, std::size_t y):m_grid(create_grid(x, y)){};

    // The length of the grid_graph along the specified dimension.
    vertices_size_type length(std::size_t d) const {return m_grid.length(d);}


    private:
    // Create the underlying rank-2 grid with the specified dimensions.
    grid create_grid(std::size_t x, std::size_t y) {
        boost::array<std::size_t, 2> lengths = { {x, y} };
        return grid(lengths);
    } 

    // The grid underlying the grid_graph
    grid m_grid;  
};


// Euclidean heuristic for a grid
//
// This calculates the Euclidean distance between a vertex and a goal
// vertex.
class euclidean_heuristic {
     // public boost::astar_heuristic<filtered_grid, double>

    public:
     euclidean_heuristic(vertex_descriptor goal):m_goal(goal) {};

    double operator()(vertex_descriptor v) {
        return sqrt(pow(m_goal[0] - v[0], 2) + pow(m_goal[1] - v[1], 2));
    }

    private:
    vertex_descriptor m_goal;
};

// Exception thrown when the goal vertex is found
struct found_goal {};

// Visitor that terminates when we find the goal vertex
struct astar_goal_visitor:public boost::default_astar_visitor 
{
    astar_goal_visitor(vertex_descriptor goal):m_goal(goal) {};

    void examine_vertex(vertex_descriptor u, const filtered_grid&) {
        if (u == m_goal)
            throw found_goal();
    }

     private:
     vertex_descriptor m_goal;
};

    void find_shortest(int start, int end, std::vector<std::map<ulong,unlong>>& 
    graph)
    {
        std::set<unlong>                              searchedList;
        std::priority_queue<std::pair<ulong, ulong>>  frontierList;

        frontierList.push(std::make_pair(0, start));

        while(!frontierList.empty())
        {
            std::pair<ulong, ulong> next = frontierList.top();
            frontierList.pop();

            if (next.second == end) {
                std::cout << "Min Cost: " << next.first << "\n";
                return;
            }
            if (searchedList.find(next.second) != searchedList.end()) {
                continue; 
            }

            searchedList.insert(next.second);

            for(std::map<ulong,unlong>::const_iterator loop = graph[next.second].begin(); loop != graph[next.second].end(); ++loop)
            {    
                frontierList.push(std::make_pair(next.first + loop->second, loop->first));
            }
        }

        boolgrid_graph::solve() {

        // The predecessor map is a vertex-to-vertex mapping.
        typedef boost::unordered_map<vertex_descriptor,
                               vertex_descriptor,
                               vertex_hash> pred_map;
        pred_map predecessor;
        boost::associative_property_map<pred_map> pred_pmap(predecessor);
        // The distance map is a vertex-to-distance mapping.
        typedef boost::unordered_map<vertex_descriptor,
                               distance,
                               vertex_hash> dist_map;
        dist_map distance;
        boost::associative_property_map<dist_map> dist_pmap(distance);

        vertex_descriptor s = source();
        vertex_descriptor g = goal();
        euclidean_heuristic heuristic(g);
        astar_goal_visitor visitor(g);

        try {
            astar_search(m_barrier_grid, s, heuristic,
                 boost::weight_map(weight).
                 predecessor_map(pred_pmap).
                 distance_map(dist_pmap).
                 visitor(visitor) );
        } catch(found_goal fg) {
            // Walk backwards from the goal through the predecessor chain adding
            // vertices to the solution path.
            for (vertex_descriptor u = g; u != s; u = predecessor[u])
                m_solution.insert(u);

            m_solution.insert(s);
            m_solution_length = distance[g];

            return true;
        }
      return false;
    }

int main(int,char*[]){

    boost::array<std::size_t, 2> lengths = { { 30,50 } };
    GraphType grid(lengths);

    if (grid_graph.solve())
        output << std::endl << "Solution length " << m.m_solution_length;
}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem as detailed as possible. Is your problem related to boost or the Dijkstra algorithm?

Comment: And please don't post code that is quite obviously just copied and pasted together with missing bits. As MVCE/SSCCE is required